# Major CSS issue; text should be white, not blue. CSS selector issue, or !important issue?

Tags: css

CSS issue. This is a WordPress site and the text in my menu items should be white.  But for some odd reason, it's showing up as blue:

[image: My top Menu]

So I firebugged it, and I really don't know what to add as custom CSS with all the selectors #, ., etc.; I've always had trouble with this:

[image: Mission is a menu item that I firegubbed, as seen below]

Lastly, here's my CSS that's supposed to be used ..

```
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item {font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 16px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul, #dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul, #dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul.menu {background: #222 url(skins/images/bg_black.png) repeat-x 0 -80px; width: 100%; height: 40px; border-right: 1px solid #1B1B1B; border-left: 1px solid #1B1B1B; position: relative;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li {float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li a {float: left; display: block; color: #fff; padding: 12px 38px 12px 25px; background: url(skins/images/bg_black.png) repeat-x 100% 0; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; text-decoration: none;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li a.dc-mega {position: relative;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li a .dc-mega-icon {display: block; position: absolute; top: 18px; right: 15px; width: 8px; height: 6px; background: url(skins/images/arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li.mega-hover a, #dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li a:hover {background-position: 100% -40px; color: #000; text-shadow: none;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li.mega-hover a .dc-mega-icon {background-position: 0 100%;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container {position: absolute; background: url(skins/images/bg_sub_left.png) no-repeat 0 100%; padding-left: 20px; margin-left: -3px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub {background: url(skins/images/bg_sub.png) no-repeat 100% 100%; padding: 20px 20px 20px 10px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container.mega .sub {padding: 20px 20px 10px 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul.full-width li .sub-container.mega .sub {margin-right: -2px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub .row {width: 100%; overflow: hidden; clear: both;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub li {list-style: none; float: none; width: 170px; font-size: 1em; font-weight: normal;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub li.mega-hdr {margin: 0 10px 10px 0; float: left;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub li.mega-hdr.last {margin-right: 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub a {background: none; border: none; text-shadow: none; color: #111; padding: 7px 10px; display: block; float: none; text-decoration: none; font-size: 0.9em;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub li.mega-hdr a.mega-hdr-a {padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px; margin-bottom: 5px; background: #6B6B6B url(skins/images/bg_mega_hdr.png) no-repeat 0 0; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub li.mega-hdr a.mega-hdr-a:hover {color: #000; text-shadow: none;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul .sub li.mega-hdr li a {padding: 4px 5px 4px 20px; background: url(skins/images/arrow_off.png) no-repeat 5px 8px; font-weight: normal;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul .sub li.mega-hdr li a:hover {color: #a32403; background: #efefef url(skins/images/arrow_on.png) no-repeat 5px 8px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul .sub ul li {padding-right: 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container.non-mega .sub {padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container.non-mega li {padding: 0; width: 190px; margin: 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container.non-mega li a {padding: 7px 5px 7px 22px; background: url(skins/images/arrow_off.png) no-repeat 7px 10px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container.non-mega li a:hover {color: #a32403; background: #efefef url(skins/images/arrow_on.png) no-repeat 7px 10px;}
```

As you can see, there's nothing blue in that CSS; I don't know where the blue is coming from.  It should be white.  Maybe I have to try putting !important after the #fff ... but that didn't seem to work either.  You can see the [menu in action here](http://www.occupyhln.org/about-us/).

Any help with this conundrum would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Links are blue by default and it looks like you're not changing their color in the CSS.

Comment: CSS Classes are your friend. This looks like massive (and in-effective) abuse of the #id selector

Comment: It's being overridden in dynamik-min.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebug, you can see that this style is being applied in `dynamik-min.css` on Line 2

```
.catalyst-widget-area a, .catalyst-widget-area a:visited {
    color: #3A639A !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Note the `!important` flag on the color attribute.

You can simply apply an `!important` to to `#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-2-item ul li a` like this:

```
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-2-item ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Axel.  That put me on the right track.  I have a few bugs to work out, but I think I can handle it from here.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

These two classes have the blue color:

```css
 .catalyst-widget-area a, .catalyst-widget-area a:visited {
   color: #3A639A !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
 }
```

This is why your text is blue. So make a new style sheet or change it.

Comment: Thanks Keith.  Is there a way I can overwrite the Catalyst default stylesheet so this menu CSS shows as it should?  Or do I really have to alter the core stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

I see a blue style applied to links:

`dynamik-min.css, line 2`

```css
.catalyst-widget-area a, .catalyst-widget-area a:visited {
  color: #3A639A !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks Showdev; it's just a matter of figuring out how to overwrite the main stylesheet with the !important ... but everybody put me on the right track.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure whey those are marked `!important` in `dynamik.min.css`. I would remove the `!important` from those definitions or set [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) definitions to override them (as mentioned in other answers).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css

```
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-2-item ul li a{color:#fff !important;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-2-item ul li a:hover{#3A639A !important}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't match an ID selector in CSS with a wildcard (at least not the way you are trying)

you can do any of these:

```
#exactCaseSensitiveMatchOnTheID{...}

div[id*='substringInTheID']{...}
```

However realistically if you want to match on multiple, similar elements... add a class to them and select by class instead.

```
div.myClassName{...}
```

Comment: Thank you Scun; appreciate the help. I really need to brush up on my CSS ... well, actually learn it from scratch!  Thanks for taking the time to respond.